# Graphs/Charts in Android

Tags: android, graph, charts

I'm a beginner in android application development. I got a requirement where I have to show some statistics in the form of graphs/charts. I would like to if there is any API as such which would suffice this requirement in android. Else, I would like to the means the other best means that would make this easy. I referred other questions regarding this, but I'm unable to decide basing on them. Help needed as soon as possible.

Comment: Please refer AchartEngine library for this

Answer (score 2):

This is good , easy to use and if You have problem PhilJay or someone else will help you on stack:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart